# Granting rights to a group of users

Tags: laravel

There is a blog. It has posts. When an admin or user adds a post, he can choose who he will be available for detailed viewing. The post must be available for viewing to the exact group of users that will be indicated for the rest will be denied access. Trying to use the Gateways, I can't handle it. On push on a thought to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you read about policies: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Laravel Gate? And if yes, then you should paste a few codes so one could see where you are going wrong. With laravel gate, it would do just fine for what you are looking for.